# C# login to custom application without password

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, security, passwords

I am working on a legacy Windows application (C#/WinForms) that has been around for a few years. This application maintains a database table of username/password to access the application and also stores the associated windows domain\username.

So... A user logs into Windows, then when the application starts, the user is presented with a login form. The user enters "application username" / "application password", which are checked against the database table. Note, the database also stores the windows domain\username for each user. The database table is more or less like this...

```
Users
UserId    |    AppUser    |   WindowsUser       |  Password    |   IsActive
1              AppUserA       domain\WinlogonA     3opas{...}      Y
2              AppUserB       domain\WinlogonB     94d4a{...}      N
```

I now need to write another application which shares the same database. The application should only run if the user is active.

Given that I can be reasonably certain, in a corporate environment, the logged on user is who they say they are, then an application specific login dialog seems redundant. I am tempted to just check that the windows user exists in the table (and is active).

Is this approach sensible or should I present a login dialog? Is there an alternative "Integrated Windows Authentication" approach that I should be using to avoid presenting a login dialog?

Comment: Check Environment class's UserName and UserDomainName property

Comment: Thanks kenny, I know how to do that. windowsidentity.getcurrent().name should suffice.. question is more security targeted as I'm suggesting avoiding the login dialog entirely on the assumption the windows login is sufficient. Feels like bad practice...